# Is there any way to reduce the noise and vibration in a C-130 Hercules?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, military, noise, c-130

We are using C-130 B and E Models with T-56 A-15 engines and Hamilton Sundstrand 54H60-91/117 propellers. A lot of vibration and resonance are felt on these military version aircraft even after using solid state synchrophasing and conducting prop balancing.

I wanted to know if there is some system to make the aircraft quieter. Except for shutting down the engines of course :)

Are there any resonance controlling items to make the passengers more at ease?

Comment: Have you tried loudspeakers and AC/DC?

Comment: Or noise cancelling headsets for everyone?

Comment: Line the cabin walls with Sound Proof material, such as  http://www.aircraftspruce.com/menus/ap/soundproof.html  or other similar material approved military use.  Of course, the walls may already be lined with something.

Comment: I really like the "shut down the engine" solution

Comment: I worked the C-130E/H my whole stint in the Air Force. To this day, I have never slept as soundly and as comfortably on an airplane as I did on those birds. When the props are synced, the hum and vibration was so relaxing. I used to string a hammock up from one side to the other and just rock away like a baby. I honestly don’t think there is anything to make it quieter as the military never really cared much about how much noise we were exposed to.

Answer (score 2):

Active vibration control systems exist for some aircraft, though I doubt an ex-military type would have anything off the shelf. There is a system from Lord (the engine mount people) that is intended to counter the vibration from a helicopter main rotor to improve passenger comfort, among other things. This is their claimed reduction:

[image]

[AVCS Product Brochure](https://www.lord.com/sites/default/files/Documents/ProductBrochures/PB6060_LORDAVCS.pdf)

They focus on helicopters but sell components as well, and may be able to customize something that could work for you.